# Could not validate a connection to Elasticsearch. Unknown 504 error from Elasticsearch null

Tags: elasticsearch, windows

Im trying to install magento 2.4.6 version in windows system. Installed elastic search 7.17 version
and commandline used is below

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://localhost:8082/magento --db-host=localhost --db-host=localhost:3309 --db-name=magento --db-user=root --db-password= --admin-firstname=admin --admin-lastname=admin --admin-email=sarahjasminey@gmail.com --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US --currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1 --backend-frontname=admin --search-engine=elasticsearch7 --elasticsearch-host=localhost --elasticsearch-port=9200
```

But throwing error "Could not validate a connection to Elasticsearch. Unknown 504 error from Elasticsearch null"

Later thought maybe compatability issues and installed elasticsearch8 and tried installation. But same error occured. Please help me to solve this

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your elasticsearch service is running. Use following command

```
sudo service elasticsearch status
```

If the service is not running user following command to start it

```
sudo service elasticsearch start
```

Comment: Elastic search is running already i have checked, and im using windows, xampp. please let me know if anything i could check with

Answer (score 0):

Please verify first that Elasticsearch active/running in your development system/server.

Magento 2.4.6 also support Open search. So you can remove `--search-engine=elasticsearch7 --elasticsearch-host=localhost --elasticsearch-port=9200`  from command.

URL : https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/system-requirements.html?lang=en

Comment: Okay i will using opensearch and will post the results soon.

Comment: how to handle opensearch, once installed i tried open it just opened and closed.